# Override buildForm() in another module

Tags: 8, forms, comments

I would like to override the `buildForm()` method of the Comment module in my custom module.

The method is defined in core/modules/comment/src/Form/CommentAdminOverview.php.

To achieve this, I've created myModuleName/src/Form/MyModuleNameCommentAdminOverview.php, whose first lines are the following.

```
namespace Drupal\myModuleName\Form; 

use Drupal\comment\CommentInterface;
use Drupal\comment\Form\CommentAdminOverview;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class myModuleNameCommentAdminOverview  extends CommentAdminOverview {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $type = 'new') {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In myModuleName.info.yml I have these lines.

```
 dependencies:
  - comment:comment
```

My code is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I have read the following, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

- [Need to override single Drupal 8 plugin function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220130/need-to-override-single-drupal-8-plugin-function)
- [Override or extend function of a contributed module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221931/override-or-extend-function-of-a-contributed-module)
- [Overriding the function of a module in another module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/overriding-the-function-of-a-module-in-another-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the two routes for the original form class:

*comment.routing.yml:*

```
comment.admin:
  path: '/admin/content/comment'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Comments'
    _form: '\Drupal\comment\Form\CommentAdminOverview'
    type: 'new'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer comments'

comment.admin_approval:
  path: '/admin/content/comment/approval'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Unapproved comments'
    _form: '\Drupal\comment\Form\CommentAdminOverview'
    type: 'approval'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer comments'
```

You have to alter both routes like this

```
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('comment.admin')) {
      $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm');
    }
  }
```

in a [RouteSubscriber](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

Comment: Many thanks by your answer. The problem persists. alterRoute() is called and It's works but my buildform() method hasn't been called.

Comment: What you should check first is the router table, you can use the module Devel (/devel/routes) or Drupal Console: `drupal debug:router comment.admin`

Comment: Just run the command myself and found out, that in D8.4 a view has replaced this route. So if you want that your code runs, you have to disable this view, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2898013