# Correct approach to extend webform submission purge conditions?

Tags: webforms

I'd like to extend the behavior of WebformSubmissionStorage's purge method (e.g. to prevent locked submissions from being purged), and add the corresponding elements in the "basic" configuration form for purge options.

The configuration form can probably be enriched by implementing hook_form_alter.
But what is the correct approach to extend the purge method ? I don't see how overriding the class could help, so there has to be another way.

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Try following the buildForm override approach described here: [Override buildForm() in another module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250265/override-buildform-in-another-module)

This would include overriding the route `entity.webform_submission.collection_purge` defined in webform.routing.yml

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However submission purging is mostly done by cron, and webform_cron() will call WebformSubmissionStorage->purge so overriding the route won't help.
Maybe the correct approach is to create another module with its own cron, its own set of parameters and its own, independant purge function called by cron.